# CakePHP Mobile Detection Not Working?

Tags: cakephp, mobile

I am not sure why this is not working! I have the code below in my beforeFilter() function inside my AppController, I am using CakePHP 2.2.2, I started using '$this->RequestHandler->isMobile()' but that gave me an error. Looking at the CakePHP website I found that they had change the call to what I now use below.

However this does not work, when I view my site on my iPhone it should only echo a test message set on the view file, however it still goes to the default.cpt file for the whole site, which I thought should have been stop with the autoRender command?

So what I am doing wrong or have I not done something I should have?

```
  if($this->request->is('mobile')) {
      $this->isMobile = true;
      $this->set('isMobile', true );
      $this->autoRender = false;
      $this->render('../mobile/test');
   }
```

Many Thanks Glenn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this? Not able to test it, but it looks like it should work.

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->is('mobile')) {
        // Execute code only if client accepts is mobile
    } else {
        // Execute Normal Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, that sort of did it, had to play around with it and do watch it, 'RequestHandler' would just display errors for me using 2.2.2, 'request' is what i had to use.

Answer (score 2):

following the well written documentation, you can do:

```
if ($this->request->is('mobile')) {
    $this->isMobile = true;
    ...
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#inspecting-the-request

that would be the new 2.x style of doing this. the requesthandler component is just a wrapper here and might some day deprecated the wrapper access.

Answer (score 0):

for cake php 2.x use this at top of your controller

`public $components = array('RequestHandler');`

and inside the any action use this

```
 if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
```

// your conditions goes here

}